# Hartl's Railtutorial: Converting error-msg partial to all object has undefined method 'f' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Following Hartl's railstutorial and I changed my error-messages partial to work with other objects http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec:edit_form.

After changing all my @user to object and passing :object => f.object when I render the partial, I get this error when I try to load up my sign up page:

`NameError in Users#new: undefined local variable or method 'f'`

and it points to this line

`<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>`

Any advice?

new.html.erb

```
<div id="mainlogo"><%= image_tag("sample_logo.png", :alt => "Sample Title", 
                                                    :class =>"round")%></div>

    <div id="errors_new">
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
    </div>

    <div id="signup_spacer"></div>

<div id="signupcontainer_new" class="round">
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<p>It's free</p>

<div id="signupform_new">
    <%= render :partial => 'users/usersignup' %>
</div>

</div>
```

_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation" class="round">


  <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <h2><%= msg %></h2>
     <% end %>


  </div>
<% end %>
```

_usersignup.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post all of `new.html.erb` please, I just want to make sure that variable `f` is passed in to the block

Comment: @stephenmurdoch It isn't--the top-level pages get a `User` object (`@user`).

Comment: @stephenmurdoch, sure thing; I posted the entire thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.object` is only valid inside the block that defines `f`, which is now in the form partial.

The line needs to be within the `form_for` block in the form partial as in [the tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code%3asignup_errors_updated).

The tutorial also creates a partial for just the fields, where that line can go.

Comment: If I move that line into my form_for, won't the error be displayed in the form?

Comment: @hyngyn Yep. If you don't want it there, then you need to pass the user into the error message partial. What I'm saying is that it's not `f` in your `new` template, it's only `f` when there's an `f` in scope--that's what the `form_for` block is doing. In `new` it's `@user`.

Comment: Got it. I changed it to this `<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => @user  %>` and it works now. Thank you for your help, Dave. I appreciate it!